# Перезаписывается кадр. Python. OpenCV, #cv2

Tags: python, opencv

Так уж случилось, что для преобразования видео я использую OpenCV. 
В процессе выполнения кода

```py
import cv2, numpy as np, sys
# RGB 57 255 20 chromagreen

def take_v_writer():
    # type(out) <class 'cv2.VideoWriter'>
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(name_of_out_video, fourcc, 60.0, (Y_OUT,X_OUT))
    return out

def take_v_capture():
    # type(vcap) <class 'cv2.VideoCapture'>
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(direct_of_input_video)
    return vidcap

def take_X_Y_size():
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(direct_of_input_video)
    success, fr = vidcap.read()
    X = fr.shape[0]
    Y = fr.shape[1]
    vidcap.release()
    return X, Y

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
    def is_empty(self):
        return self.items == []
    def enqueue (self,item):
        self.items.insert(0, item)
    def dequeue (self):
        return self.items.pop()
    def size    (self):
        return len(self.items)


fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
name_of_out_video = 't(h)_0001 .avi'
direct_of_input_video = 'C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/py/openCv/0002.avi'
X_OUT = 480
Y_OUT = 640

FRAME00 = np.zeros((X_OUT,Y_OUT,3), np.uint8)
FRAME00[0:,0:] = (20,255,57)
#X_IN, Y_IN = take_X_Y_size()

q_frames = Queue()
# q_frames size must be equal X_OUT
#cv2.imshow('sadf',FRAME00)
#cv2.waitKey(0)
for i in range(X_OUT):
    q_frames.enqueue(FRAME00)

vout = take_v_writer()
# vout = cv2.VideoWriter(name_of_video, fourcc, 60.0, (Y_OUT,X_OUT))
vin = take_v_capture()
success, frame = vin.read()
haha = 0

while (success):   
    #ii = 0
    resized = cv2.resize(frame,(Y_OUT,X_OUT))

    for i in reversed(range((X_OUT))):
        q_frames.items[i][i:i+1,0:] = resized[i:i+1,0:]
        #ii += 1

    finalframe = q_frames.dequeue()
    vout.write(finalframe)
    q_frames.enqueue(FRAME00)

    success, frame = vin.read()


    print('{0} frame'.format(haha))
    haha += 1

for i in range(q_frames.size()):
    finalframe = q_frames.dequeue()
    vout.write(finalframe)

cv2.imshow('sd', FRAME00) # здесь кадр из видео
cv2.waitKey(0) # а должен быть зеленый сплошной
print('GmOver')
vin.release()
vout.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

переменная **FRAME00** перезаписывается (выдает кадр из видео, хотя должен быть сплошной кадр зеленого цвета) 
Перезапись идет где-то в цикле **while** , но я не нашел где. Возможно это какие то сюрпризы библиотеки?

Answer (score 0):

Выяснил, что проблема не в **OpenCV**, а в **numpy**. В момент

```py
for i in range(X_OUT):
    q_frames.enqueue(FRAME00)
```

в массив **q_frames** записывается ссылка на один и тот же объект. Решение проблемы простое, воспользоваться командами из **numpy**, когда это необходимо для копирования элементов массива

```py
for i in range(X_OUT):
   q_frames.enqueue(FRAME00.copy())
```